# What is the best solution to make textview dimensions fit to all screens?

Tags: android, textview, width

I am generating textview in my app dynamically and i want make its width and height compatible to all screens . 
I am using the following code to make that but when testing it on Galaxy s3, i found it very small despite the same dimensions is good in tablets ... 
So what is the best solution to do that ??

Thanks in advance :)

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            int textSize = 0;

            if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
                width = 30;
                height = 30;
                textSize = 24;
                Log.e("small", "small");
            } else if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
                width = 55;
                height = 55;
                textSize = 24;
                Log.e("normal", "normal");
            } else if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                width = 45;
                height = 45;
                textSize = 32;
                Log.e("large", "large");
            } else {
                Log.e("xlarge", "xlarge");
                width = 60;
                height = 60;
                textSize = 40;
            }

            // http://www.designbyexperience.com/px-to-dp-converter/

            spaceViews[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));

            spaceViews[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            spaceViews[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: use `sp` for textview size like `android:textSize="18sp"`

Comment: I don't speak about text itself this textview has a background and this background is very small

Answer (score 0):

you can try this github link [android library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).

Answer (score 0):

Use the method for consitency in all devices:

```
int dpToPx(final int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```